# How to schedule a ride with uber api?

Tags: uber-api

There is no option in uber api documentation to schedule rides for future.

But the following products provide Uber pre-booking:

https://www.ridesharp.co/
https://www.trykommen.com/

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just providing their own mechanism to 'schedule' a ride. All they are doing is storing the time & details for the request and then making the request call at the appointed time. There is no scheduled ride API.

Comment: And how can we acquire that? Is there any reference or code snippet ?